# Printing an Integer and their half calling it from main method

Tags: java, math

Im only started learning java. Im practicing on how to print and half integer

I have define the main method and for the halfing method I have also define it in the same class but it wont compile. Any suggestions? this is my code

```
public class IntAndHalf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double y;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + y);
        }
    }
    public static double halfOfint(int i){
        for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
            y = i/2;
            return (y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well y is nowhere defined and you are making an integer division, you are not calling your method, these are your problems

Comment: `y` is not defined / declared in the main method

Comment: ohh right maybe i should change it to double for the halfing method? I initialize y = 0?

Comment: **1**. there is a `;` after your loop, **2**. `y` is not defined in main **3**. you take `y` as a parameter, but set it to `0`

Comment: You need to 'return ((double) i)/2 in your method, and you are not defining the variable y inside your main function and therefore getting an compiler error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You have a lot of problem in your code :

- `y` is not define in your main method
- The `i` is already declared in your method, so you have not
  to declare it again in your loop `(int i = 0;)` just use it `(i = 0;)`.
- Your miss `;` in the end of `y = (i/2)`
- When you make `;` in the end of your loop, the next block
  will not executed `for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++ );`
- You have to `return(y)` in the end of your method not in your
  loop

---

Correct this typos and your code will compiled, another thing you never call your method HalfOfInt so don't wait to get information from this method, you have to call in your main method.

---

Edit

Your code in this case should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "-" + HalfOfInt(i));
        //                              ^-----------call your method which
                                                  //take an int and return the (i/2)
        //                 ^-------------------------Print your value
    }
}

public static double HalfOfInt(int i) {
    return (double) i / 2;//<<----------- no need to use a loop just return (i/2)
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code. Im still unsure what you mean by defining `y` in my main method. can you check the updated version please. thanks

Comment: you have to declare it and initialize it @Kutam `double y = 0;`

Comment: what you expect to get from your metod @Kutam ?

Comment: ok i have updated the `y = 0` under the line `public static void main(....)`. So for the main method, im trying to print an integer from 1-20, and the second method, I want to display the half of those numbers.

Comment: so you want to print `1-0.5, 2-1, 3-1.5....` @Kutam ? is that what you want

Comment: wow im actually surprise how much more simple this is. I think I complicate things too much. greatly appreacited :)

Comment: @Kutam note you can use it also without calling your method so instead of `System.out.println(i + "-" + HalfOfInt(i));` you can use `System.out.println(i + "-" + ((double) i / 2));` no need to your method HalfOfInt :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple Problems** :

1. There is a `;` after your `for` loop.
2. `y` is **not** defined in your main method.
3. You are missing a `;` after `y = (i/2)`
4. You never call `HalfOfInt`
5. You declare `i` twice.

Also, you should stick with Java naming conventions. Methods should begin with a *lower-case letter*.